# Is this implementation of the `mv` command the most appropriate? It can be improved?

Tags: c, file-system, shell

I wrote a program that implements the same function as the `mv` command.

I know this is not the best implementation, so I would like some suggestions for improvement, possible problems. What you should change?

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  char *source, *destination, *new_source, *new_destination;
  char *current_directory;
  if (argc != 3) {
    printf("usage- %s source destination\n", *argv);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  // work on copy
  source = (char*)malloc(strlen(argv[1]) + 1);
  strcpy(source, argv[1]);
  destination = (char*)malloc(strlen(argv[2]) + 1);
  strcpy(destination, argv[2]);
            
            current_directory = getenv("PWD");
            new_source = (char*)malloc(strlen(source) + 1 + strlen(current_directory) + 1);
            strcpy(new_source,current_directory);
            strcat(new_source,"/");
            strcat(new_source,source);
  new_destination = (char*)malloc(strlen(destination) + 1 + strlen(current_directory) + 1 + strlen(source) + 1);
  strcpy(new_destination,current_directory);
  strcat(new_destination,"/");
  strcat(new_destination,destination);
  strcat(new_destination,"/");
  strcat(new_destination,source);
  
  /*execute systemcall*/
  if(rename(new_source,new_destination) != 0){
    fprintf(stderr,"eroare: %s\n",strerror(errno));
  }
  free(new_source);
  free(new_destination);
  free(source);
  free(destination);
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Nice to see the use of the standard `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE`.

The return value from the `rename()` system call can actually be a check against `EXIT_SUCCESS` because that system call is returning either `EXIT_SUCCESS` or `EXIT_FAILURE`.

### From main() Use Return Rather Than Exit

Since all of this is happening in the `main()` function there is no reason to use the `exit()` function. Since the operating system entry point is `main()` `return` and `exit` are equivalent.

### Too Much Work

It isn't clear why it was necessary to copy the strings from `argv` to strings, it should be easy enough to use the `argv` strings directly, this removes the need to call `malloc()` and `free()` which also use system calls and therefore affect the performance of the program.

### Error Prevention

The code should check that the source file named in `argv[1]` exists and can be opened.

Answer (score 3):

- Never cast what `malloc` returns. It is not necessary, and may lead to hard-to-find bugs.
- `strcpy(), strcat(), strcat()` sequence is anti-idiomatic. Prefer

  ```
   sprintf(new_source, "%s/%s", current_directory, source);
  ```
- Prefixing the source and destination with `PWD` seriously limits usability of the program: it can't deal with absolute paths at all.

  Along the same line, the `destination` is always treated like a directory name. It is not how `mv` is supposed to wrok.